# CycleJS HTTP request$ not firing requests

Tags: cyclejs

New to CycleJS, I'm trying to read some data from an HTTP driver, and write to it when the user makes changes. I have the following:

An initial request is just a simple GET.

```
const initialRequest$ = Observable.just({url: ...});
```

Based on some captured user intent, I update my model and create (or try to create at least) a PATCH request to update the remote data.

```
const patchRequests$ = intent$
    .withLatestFrom(model$, (intent, model) => {
        const payload = ... // get payload from model and intent
        return {
            url: `my/url/${target}`,
            method: 'PATCH',
            send: {
                // payload...
            },
        };
    });
```

Then I merge the streams together with:

```
const request$ = Observable.merge(initialRequest$, patchRequests$);
```

and return `request$` to the HTTP driver.

My initial request goes through just fine and I get the data in the HTTP source stream. But the patches never fire.

I can subscribe to the `request$` with something like:

```
request$.subscribe((req) => console.log(req));
```

And I'll see my initial request and patch requests all logged to the console. But still the patch requests are never sent.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `eager: true` as one of the properties of the request object. Otherwise, the HTTP Driver ignores requests that don't have a corresponding response$ waiting for it in the application.

This will change in a future version of Cycle.js, though, all requests will be eager and you wouldn't see this problem.